# Firebase 3.x - Facebook Login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

In`Firebase 2.5.1`, I used to do this, and it was working:

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

   let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager() 

  facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            myRootRef.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Logged in!")
                        let newUser = [
                            "provider": user.provider,  
                            "imageUrl": user!.providerData["profileImageURL"] as String,    // etc
                        ]
                    }
             })
         }
   })
}
```

Now I am trying to achieve this in `Firebase 3.x`. However, I got confused on where I should place permissions and stuff

This is what I tried so far

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

   let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

   let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

   FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Login failed. \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Logged in!")

        let newUser = [
           "provider": user.provider,
           "imageUrl": user!.providerData["profileImageURL"] as String
        ]
    }
   })
}
```

**Update:**

```
 facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
    if facebookError != nil {
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
    } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
        print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
    } else {
        // your firebase authentication stuff..

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Login failed. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Logged in!")

                let userID = Helpers.extractUID(user!)

                let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                let userRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userID)

                userRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                        let newUser = [
                            "providerId": user?.providerID,
                            "displayName": user?.displayName,
                        ]
                       userRef.setValue((newUser as! AnyObject))
                       // perform segue
                    }
                })
             }
         })
```

Comment: in else part ...add this stuff  ... `if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {  let credential ...  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you successfully login with facebook and get user data back ... you have to add firebase authentication stuff like

```
 @IBAction func facebookLoginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

   let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager() 

   facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            // your firebase authentication stuff..

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                  print("Login failed. \(error)")
            } else {
                 print("Logged in!")

            }
          })
        }
   })
}
```

Comment: In 'your firebase authentication stuff', should I include something else or you meant `let credential...` stuff?